# Automation of Downloads in Web Browsers

Tags: web, automation, download

What is the reason for automating download links in websites?

It could have the benefit of sparing the user a click, except that the browser *always* blocks it (you have to click on the yellow bar that appears at the top of the browser).  That's harder than just clicking on the link that says, "If your download doesn't start automatically, click here."

If I'm building my own website, should I be concerned about adding this kind of automation?  It doesn't seem to me like it adds much value, yet many websites do it anyway.  Are they doing it because everyone else is doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the pages where you have clicked to download and then you get that "your download will start automatically in XX secs"?

The reason for this is generally so the website can show you a page of ads while you're downloading.

The ad page kicks off the download automatically so you don't have to click again to really get the download.

Comment: Except that you *always* have to click again to get the download, because the browser will block the automation, for security reasons.

Comment: Agreed, but the purpose of the page remains the same - to serve you some ads.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the user to watch an ad, or have a screen to validate that they're using a genuine copy of Windows or somesuch, yes, you'll need that screen.

Otherwise, skip it.